# How can I communicate Raspberry Pi and Arduino (in both ways) using a 10-15m distance wires?

Tags: serial, uart

I am starting a personal project of home automation and I have a raspberry pi and an arduino Uno board.

I want communicate raspberry pi and my arduino where my raspberry should be able to write and read signals to and from arduino.

The distance between them I think its going to be something around 10 to 15 meters.

What do I need for it? what kind of wires or other components I'll need to achieve my goal? I repeat: I do not want to communicate raspberry pi and arduino wirelessly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

for length such as this, you should be using protocols that are designed for length, such as:

- UART,
- CAN,
- Ethernet

for UART, you can't of course use a direct connection between the two boards, you need to upgrade the connection and wiring to either rs232 or rs485, using a driver between the arduino pins and the cable.

Though, the simplest solution would be to plug the Arduino on the Raspberry Pi using a lengthy USB cable (or more likely 3 five meters cable), which should work fine as long as you only do serial communication. The USB 2.0 limitation of 5 meters are for "hi-speed" connections, which is not our concern for simple serial data communication.

HTH